# Use other table & column names for authenticate function in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have pre existing table with table name='XYZUsers' which columns names as user_id, XYZ_password.

I want use authenticate function in django by passing user_id, XYZ_password instead of using normal username , password.

How I can acheive this?

```
Models.py
class XYZUsers(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    XYZ_password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'xyz_users'


views.py
def Login_user(request,Username,Password):
    print(Username)
    print(Password)
    
    try:
        PYX_Users=XYZUsers.objects.get(user_id=Username)
   
    except Exception as e:
        print('user not avaialble')

    PYX_Users=authenticate(request,PYX_Users.user_id=Username,PYX_Users.XYZ_password=Password)
    print(PYX_Users)
    if Gains_Users is not None:
        auth_login(request,PYX_Users)
        return JsonResponse(str('1'),safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse(str('0'),safe=False)
```